# SQL How do I use the parentheses correctly to separate the AND and OR statements?

Tags: sql, concrete5

I'm not super awesome at SQL. I'm filtering a concrete5 collection with the following and not sure how to get all of it working. How do I use the parentheses correctly to separate the AND and OR statements?

This doesn't do anything:

```
$this->filter(null, "(
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
                OR
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
                OR
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
            )
            AND
            (DATE_ADD(warnedDate, INTERVAL 4 DAY) <= NOW())");
```

This one mostly works (removed parentheses around the statements before the AND) but doesn't seem to filter the clause after AND... the "DATE_ADD(warnedDate, INTERVAL 4 DAY) <= NOW())":

```
$this->filter(null, "
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
                OR
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
                OR
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())

            AND
            (DATE_ADD(warnedDate, INTERVAL 4 DAY) <= NOW())");
```

Comment: Your first statement seem to be correct. Try to remove `AND (DATE_ADD(warnedDate, INTERVAL 4 DAY) <= NOW())");` to verify that `OR` logic is working as intended. Than add it back. as general rule you use you need to wrap `OR` to make sure that logic is correct `(somelogic or somelogic ) and (someotherlogic)`

Comment: `OR
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
                OR
                (DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())`
don't do anything because your first condition (30 days) includes interval of 5 and 1 day to now so remove them

Comment: @SaUce The OR logic seems to be working without the AND and statement proceeding it.. I wonder why when the AND .. is there it doesn't work..

Comment: @CaitlinHavener maybe there's no record that satisfies the condition under `AND` Check your data.

Comment: Yeah I guess I needed to add IS NULL or condition.. anywho, all is working now! Thanks guys!

Comment: What is `expirationDate`  and `warnedDate`? Are those attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the two clauses for 5 day and 1 day are redundant, because a 30 day interval to today already includes 5,1 day to today so remove them.
Try something like this

```
(DATE_SUB(expirationDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW())
AND
(DATE_ADD(warnedDate, INTERVAL 4 DAY) <= NOW())
```

**NOTE**: `AND` is used when you want BOTH of the conditions to be true and `OR` for at least one condition to be true.

Comment: That's not working either :( The program is filtering users whose membership is expiring 30 days, 5, and 1 day before their expiration and notifying them. It inserts a timestamp (warnedDate) when the user is warned. I put expiration date on one of the users for 30 days from now and it did not notify. Also, if I want to notify 30,5, and 1 days before, don't I need those statements that you deleted?

Comment: This seems to work fine for me with test data. you dont need those statements in OR because any expiration date that is within 30 days until today already is within the range of 5 days(or 1 day) to today